# Swift - map dictionary based on keys

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, enumeration

**Consider the dictionary :**

```
var dict : [String : String]! = ["12" : "This", "5" : "is", "52" : "a", "42" : "Test"]

var keys = Array(dict.keys)

var values : [String]! = [String]()
for (_, key) in keys.enumerated() {
    values.append(dict[key]!)
}
```

Will `Array(dict.values)` yield the same result as above?

Is there an easier way to map the `dictionary` based on `keys` and not `enumerate` them?

Asking because I'd like to use the same `keys` to map **`different dictionaries`** for their values.

**PS: It doesn't have to be sorted.**

**EDITED**

Consider the json below :

```
{
  "data": {
    "forecast_numbers": {
      "15": 6397822,
      "20": 985448,
      "76": 2499160,
      "130": 4480161
    },
    "actual_numbers": {
      "15": 6344454,
      "20": 1645125,
      "76": 1644789,
      "130": 2451170
    },
    "accuracy": {
      "15": -0.83415887469204,
      "20": 66.941837621062,
      "76": -34.18632660574,
      "130": -45.288350128489
    },
    "xaxis": {
      "15": "ABC",
      "20": "BCD",
      "76": "BNM",
      "130": "NNN"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to plot `forecast_numbers` & `actual_numbers` `values` against `xaxis` values. Would like to know if there is an alternate way other than using `enumerated()` for getting the values?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do, but you would get exactly the same result with `let values = Array(dict.values)`.

Comment: Do you want to get all values from the dictionary ?

Comment: @MartinR You should make that an answer.

Comment: Perhaps `let values = keys.map { dict[$0] ?? "<N/A>"}` is what you are looking for? It would allow you to get the values of another dictionary for the same keys.

Comment: @Akaino: Thank you for the suggestion, but I prefer to wait until the question has been clarified.

Comment: @MartinR Aye, you're probably right. There should be more users thinking that way. Including me, obviously.

Comment: If you only need keys... ```let the_keys: [String] = dict.keys.flatMap({ $0 })```

Comment: @MartinR updated the question.

Comment: @Adolfo Updated. Please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your purpose is not clear enough with seeing your updated example, but if you just want to gather the values for the same key each, you can write something like this:

```
let data = json["data"] as! [String: [String: Any]]
let result = data["xaxis"]!.map {($0.key, $0.value, data["forecast_numbers"]![$0.key]!, data["actual_numbers"]![$0.key]!)}
print(result) //->[("130", NNN, 4480161, 2451170), ("20", BCD, 985448, 1645125), ("76", BNM, 2499160, 1644789), ("15", ABC, 6397822, 6344454)]
```

Assuming you have that JSON data in `json` as `[String: AnyObject]`.

(Also assuming your `json` never contains some broken data. Seemingly using too much `!`.)

Comment: Thank you. was looking for something similar to this :)